# GIF under ng-hide element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know that when using a GIF in an HTML element, the thread that runs my JS is the same thread that plays the GIF.

I was wondering what happens when the GIF is under a `ng-hide="true"` element, does it still consumes CPU time?

For example:

```
<div ng-hide="true" class="splash-image"></div>
```

> The `splash-image` class brings in the GIF.

In the above case, is the thread spending CPU time on playing the invisible GIF?

Thanks

Comment: instead of ng-hide and ng-show, my suggestion is to use ng-if and by this case the dom element will be removed. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: I need it to be hidden (or removed) after something happens..

Comment: you can use an expression: ng-if="expression"

Comment: To my knowledge, `ng-if` is being evaluated when the page first renders. What if I need this to be hidden after it was rendered and something happened?

Comment: check this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview   in addition please describe the scenarion and It will be more clear

Comment: The scenario is irrelevant here.. we were off-topic. 
The question is well defined, isn't it?

Comment: ng-show/ng-hide does not remove the elements from DOM. It uses CSS styles to hide/show elements. This way your handlers that were attached to children will not be lost. hope that this is answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

There's two areas using memory: downloading the gif, and painting it in the browser.

As others have mentioned in the comments, ng-if removes the element from the DOM where ng-hide simply applies `display: none` to the element.

If you run a couple tests using the console, you can see that despite removing the element from the DOM, the asset is still downloaded even if the ng-if condition returns false.

So basically both ng-if and ng-hide download the asset, but neither spend resources painting the element. The only difference is that after downloading the asset, ng-if omits it from the DOM.

Below you can see the paint results of a normal image, then an image with ng-hide.

[image]